# Anybody know what kind of chili plant this is? Is it dead or can I revive it?

Tags: houseplants, vegetables, chili

[image][image]

I got this plant last year and it started dying. I recently brought it inside and it looks like it’s getting new leafs. Any recommendations?

Comment: There is new life in your plant.  Cut just above a new bud and make sure this plant is in a south facing window.  You said you just brought it inside?  What did you do for acclimation going from out of doors to indoors?  Where was it originally?  When plants are used to the out of doors to take them inside is a kiss of death.  Same for plants inside to be taken out of doors.  I would take this plant out during the day, under a porch roof and bring it in for the night.  Do not expect it to thrive indoors without a transition period.  Tell us more to help you with this transition!

Comment: Peppers are considered annuals in most zones.  Where do you live?  Growing plants for flowers or fruit is pretty much  a losing proposition indoors.  To keep your pepper growing inside, do not expect flowers or fruit.  You need a real artificial grow light.  Please take this plant back out of doors during the day, bring in for night time.  Cut the time spent out of doors by a hour each day until your plant is used to the indoor environment.  Even with artificial lights.

Comment: Not going to get chillis without a lot of effort in winter. Get a new plant in Spring.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies. It was originally an indoor plant and I took it outside for a couple months and just brought it in. I think I didn’t let it transition. I live in Okinawa it’s winter right now but it’s not that cold.

Comment: You're far better off getting a new plant.  Sure you might be able to coax a few chillis out of it in Summer but you won't get lots which you get with a new plant.  And inside the plants are more likely to get infected with spider mites etc.

Comment: My chili plant produced only a handful of fruits the first season and when I brought it in for the winter it progressively lost almost all of its leaves. I practically gave up on it but decided I might as well put it outdoors again in spring. I gave it a larger pot and it grew magnificently.

Answer (score 3):

What chili plant: it is difficult in such state.

In any case, it is not dead. You see new leaves. You should prune the dry branches, and remove the old (dry) leaves. It will quickly recover.

Contrary on the question's comments, I think it is worth trying: you will for sure learn something about pepper plants. I find also nice plants to have on dining room in the winter, to get some green (which is not throwaway). My plants usually have many peppers (and many were edible but ornamental varieties, so many small pepper: green and red: nice to see.

Your error (if it was not just suddenly bad weather): plants need to be  acclimated, on both ways. Before to put such plants indoor, try to put in a warm outside place for a week (e.g. near a wall). The same should be done when you put plants outside. For a week put them in an intermediate place.

Comment: Agree - it is alive. I've seen them do this during winter when I might bring them in and I think poor light is the issue. They do like light. I have some in my office here and I put a grow lamp next to them and they didn't shed.  I would venture it is a variety of Capsicuum Annum but impossible to say any more. Wait till you have fruit and you'll be able to get it down to the 'family' of variety (jalapeno, Anaheim, bell, etc).

Comment: Just needs a bit of TLC, bring the light levels up and lots of ventilation, chili's love heat! feed with a high nitrogen feed at first- get the leaves back and then a high potash feed to get the flowers and fruit forming- I've had plants last for years! trick is to remove the fruit as soon as its ripe or the plant dies.